# Add files to an xcode project from the script

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to add libraries and some testcase script files to my xcode project. I've gone through some links which shows a way of doing it from the shell script.

But the problem is "I don't want to use xcode GUI even for adding the script to the project". I'm building the app from commandline tool xcodebuild.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We’re creating static library projects from scratch with: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj.